# javascript getelementsbyname from dropdown(database)

Tags: javascript, opencart

Cant get value of my dropdown(populate from my database):

tpl:

```
<div class="form-group required">
<label>Region/state:</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select name="<?php echo $type; ?>_zone_id" id="input-<?php echo $type; ?>-zone" class="form-control" onchange="setCities2();">
</select>
</div>
</div>

<p>testzone:</p><p id = 'input-payment-zone1'></p>

<script>
function setCities2() {
document.getElementById("input-payment-zone1").innerHTML = document.getElementsByName("<?php echo $type; ?>_zone_id");
}
</script>
```

Any advice?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList`. `innerHTML` is a string property; so it’ll always be `[object NodeList]`. You actually need to iterate over the `NodeList` to get the elements, then extract some value via a property from the elements.

Comment: You should check the return of getElementById before trying to use it, this will give you some indication of where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName will return a array of values so you must try something like the code below

```
document.getElementById("input-payment-zone1").innerHTML = document.getElementsByName("<?php echo $type; ?>_zone_id")[0].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using" document.getElementsByName("_zone_id"); "

Use " document.getElementsByName("_zone_id").value;"

We have Highlighted it in the code. It is shown below:

```
<script>
function setCities2() {
document.getElementById("input-payment-zone1").innerHTML = document.getElementsByName("<?php echo $type; ?>_zone_id").value;
}
</script>
```

I hope it helps. Please let us know if your problem is resolved.

Thank you.